# Oniguruma pattern - end of the line will not work

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a field like that named **problem**:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null\\n09:56:49.712 pl.com.agora.api.client.rest.invocation.FutureCallbacksSupport {HttpClient@2052321524-scheduler} ERROR : Uri invocation failure callback failed.
```

And I want to exclude from it **exception**.

```
(?<exception>java(.*)Exception\z)
```

So I will have field **exception** with value: **java.lang.NullPointerException**

Can not seem to find end of the line which would work. \z or \Z are not working like I want it to.
Didn't find the answer here as well: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Docs-for-Oniguruma-Regular-Expressions-(RE.txt)

It is used in logstash and grok match:

```
filter {
  grok {
      match => { "message" => '%{TIME:timestamp} (\[)?(%{DATA:logger})?(\])? \{%{DATA:thread}\} %{LOGLEVEL:level} : (?<problem>(.|\r|\n)*)' }
      remove_field => ["message"]
      }
  grok {
      match => { "problem" => '(?<exception>java(.*)Exception\z)' }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full regex you have and how you use the regex you wrote.

Comment: Hi @Progman. It's so far second and whole regex that I have. It will be used in elasticsearch and logstash

Comment: @MartaZagrajek The tokens `\z`, `\Z` and `$` are used to find the end of line or end of content in your input string, but your regex doesn't use any of these tokens. Please [edit] the your question to include a detailed description of what you want to do and how actually you use the regex in your application/code.

Comment: @Amadan but you can use Oniguruma patterns in grok. I removed \z from this but added it now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The regex `(?<exception>java(.*)Exception\z)` will search for the following content:

1. The word `java`
2. Any content, including an empty string (`.*`)
3. The word `Exception`
4. The end of the input `\z`

However, there is no word "Exception" at the end of the input (`\z`). You have additional content between "Exception" and the end of the input. So you have to match this additional input as well. It might be as simple as:

```
(?<exception>java(.*)Exception).*\z
```

This will be split up into:

1. The word `java`
2. Any content, including an empty string (`.*`)
3. The word `Exception`
4. Any content, including an empty string (`.*`)
5. The end of the input (`\z`)

Which capture brackets you need depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you very much for this complex explanation ! I see that here is working: https://regex101.com/r/42e0vp/1 but on grok debugger in elasticsearch not, so I will continue to work on that.